# How to change lowercase hex to uppercase with efibootmgr?

Tags: grub2, uefi, ssd, efibootmgr

Lowercase hex appears to be a problem for grub2:

```
:~$ sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb`

Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
** Warning ** : Boot000a is not EFI 1.10 compliant (lowercase hex in name)
** Warning ** : Boot000b is not EFI 1.10 compliant (lowercase hex in name)
** Warning ** : please recreate these using efibootmgr to remove this warning.
** Warning ** : Boot000a is not EFI 1.10 compliant (lowercase hex in name)
** Warning ** : Boot000b is not EFI 1.10 compliant (lowercase hex in name)
** Warning ** : please recreate these using efibootmgr to remove this warning.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

So, lowercase hex is used and this prevents booting from Grub2.

```
:~$ modprobe efivars

:~$ sudo efibootmgr

** Warning ** : Boot000a is not EFI 1.10 compliant (lowercase hex in name)
** Warning ** : Boot000b is not EFI 1.10 compliant (lowercase hex in name)
** Warning ** : please recreate these using efibootmgr to remove this warning.
BootCurrent: 000B
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,000B,000A,0000,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0004  CD/DVD Drive
Boot000a* Hard Drive
Boot000b* UEFI: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222BB
```

The man pages say `:~$ sudo efibootmgr -b` but not how to implement this.

Additional info:

The problem of not being able to boot from grub2 began after a regular update of packages (which included a Grub2 package).

Ubuntu 14.04 2 64bit was booted with the program ReFind on a CD: Boot000b* UEFI: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222BB

Above we see BootCurrent can be capitalized automatically: BootCurrent: 000B. So, the process could have been automated. However, Boot000a and b remain in lowercase.

---

The situation has changed: when I ran efibootmgr with verbose option -v, I noticed that the boot order was changed (not shown). Above you see that the windows boot manager and ubuntu do not have lower case hex. I tried the original UEFI configuration with Ubuntu first and windows second and no REFIND CD. Now I can boot into Ubuntu, but only via recovery mode.

`:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v`

`** Warning ** : Boot000a is not EFI 1.10 compliant (lowercase hex in name)
** Warning ** : please recreate these using efibootmgr to remove this warning.
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0004,000A
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,800,84000,7e32cd58-blabla)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS... blabla
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,800,84000,7e32cd58-blabla)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0004  CD/DVD Drive  BIOS(3,0,00)P4: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222BB  .
Boot000a  Hard Drive    BIOS(2,0,00)P1: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB .`

It is puzzling that ubuntu can boot in recovery mode now (I did nothing to affect grub). Any comments? This does not solve the lowercase hex question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the warning you're seeing is a red herring. The `Boot000a is not EFI 1.10 compliant (lowercase hex in name)` and related messages are clearly marked as warnings, not errors. (In computers, a "warning" is almost always a notification to users that something is sub-optimal or that it *might* cause problems in some situations, whereas an "error" denotes a show-stopping problem.) Note that your example output includes the following statement:

```
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

In other words, everything *should* be working; the warnings have not prevented installation of GRUB.

I've also tried to track down what's causing the warnings, and it's the `efibootmgr` utility:

http://efibootmgr.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.5.4-2ubuntu1/efibootmgr_8c-source.html

The code that generates the warning does nothing but display the warning message; it does not set flags that would have other follow-on negative effects.

That said, it's conceivable that some follow-on program, such as the GRUB binary, might also have problems with lowercase hexadecimal numbers, *not* generate a warning, but fail when it sees them. That seems unlikely, though; AFAIK, GRUB doesn't consult the EFI `Boot####` variables, so if GRUB is launching, you're probably past the point where they should matter.

Another point about this is that the names of the boot options with lowercase hexadecimal numbers suggests that they were created by your firmware. Thus, even if you were to delete those boot options, they or other options with lowercase hexadecimal numbers might be (re-)created by the firmware in the future. The warning says that the values are not compliant with EFI 1.10, but most modern computers ship with EFI 2.x (aka UEFI). Thus, the warning *should* matter only on these older EFIs.

This brings me to the real heart of the matter: You've described the scary-but-probably-red-herring warning, but you haven't described what the *actual problem* is, at least not in enough detail to be useful. You note that you lost the ability to boot after you updated some packages, but that's a very vague description of the problem. Does GRUB come up at all? If GRUB comes up, does it show a menu? If GRUB tries to launch a kernel, does it hang, and if so, what type of output appears first? You mentioned use of rEFInd, but did it enable you to boot Linux any better? If not, what symptoms appeared when you booted with rEFInd? The answers to these questions are critical to solving your actual problem. I suggest you post a new question with this information and pay less attention to the (apparently harmless) `efibootmgr` warning.

Comment: "red herring": I think you are right that I was side-tracked by this warning. Thank you.
"real heart of the matter": Before I could ask this question, I got an anonymous threat that people did not like my questions and that I could be barred from asking questions in the future. So, I decided on an unambiguous one-topic question.